# Is it possible for a digitally signed application to be infected by a virus?

Tags: virus, malware, digital-signature

I downloaded "java development kit" from  my college computer, the computer that I used to download the software was full of virus and malware.   I scanned the software with antivirus program the software was ok . I checked the software properties and there was a  Digital signature on the software.

[image: Digital Signature snapshot]

So I wanted to ask following 2 questions :

1. Does a digital signature on application guarantees that it has not been infected by virus or altered by any means ?
2. Is it possible that the digital signature remains intact even after the software get infected by virus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [it](http://cioandleader.com/content/hackers-steal-digital-certificates) [is](http://news.techworld.com/security/3299976/hackers-steal-google-security-certificate-could-target-gmail-users/) [possible](http://www.itnews-blog.com/it/83470.html), but it is highly unlikely that you will be affected by such a thing. It does, happen, however.

A [digital signature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962053.aspx) does not guarantee that a program is free from malware - yes, it's supposed to, but if someone cracks into a database and steals digital signatures / certificates they can sign whatever they please. If the verification path can be trusted, then a digital signature will tell whether the integrity of the program is compromised (i.e., the program has been modified after it was signed).

Comment: … or if somebody breaks into Oracle and infects their software just before they sign it.

Comment: @ekaj ok i got it . so here in my case,  the computer that i used to download the application was infected by virus, however application's digital signature is ok . so is there any chance that executable is infected ?

Comment: !) Did you download the JDK (Java Development Kit) from Oracle? 2), you might find this read on false positives interesting and helpful in your situation - http://service1.symantec.com/sarc/sarc.nsf/info/html/what.false.positive.html