# How to verify download of TortoiseHg software for Windows

Tags: mercurial, tortoise-hg, md5sum

When installing software onto my PC, I generally like to run a hash check against my download before installing it. Many download pages provide an MD5sum to use for this kind of check.

See: [Some random page on the net that explains this practice](http://www.vmware.com/download/md5.html).

I have just downloaded TortoiseHg software for Windows from http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/ but I cannot see the MD5 mentioned anywhere.

I may be missing it. Do you know where I can find the hash code for the latest download packages?

Comment: Although not a 100% guarantee, is the app digitally signed?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure. I don't tend to click on anything I've downloaded until I check the MD5sum. How would I tell if it were digitally signed?

Comment: Ok I have right-clicked on it and looked at properties and yes, there seems to be a tab for Digital Signatures.

Comment: Yeah, I see a digital sig by Steven Borho on Dec. 12. In the absence of a checksum I guess this is the best you can do to ensure that the file hasn't been tampered with (see [Is it possible for a digitally signed application to be infected by a virus?](http://superuser.com/questions/517690/is-it-possible-for-a-digitally-signed-application-to-be-infected-by-a-virus))

Comment: Thanks for the link to that question. Apt because it was just occurring to me too.